# Wordpress Contact Form 7 writing to Database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm adding the following code to my functions.php file, but I can't seem to get the contact form to write to the Wordpress database.  I can make it write a new row, but it won't save any of the form data.  Anyone have any recommendations?

```
enter code here

function contactform7_before_send_mail( $form_to_DB )
{
//set your db details
$mydb = new wpdb('username','password','dbname','host');

$form_to_DB = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
if ( $form_to_DB )
    $formData = $form_to_DB->get_posted_data();
$title = $formData['title'];

$mydb->insert( 'name of db', array( 'title' =>$title ), array( '%s' ) );

remove_all_filters ('wpcf7_before_send_mail');
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'contactform7_before_send_mail' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to install Advanced Contact form 7 DB plugin.so it will store all the data on form submission.